# CAD Model rotations and translations in Dash VTK

Tags: python, plotly-dash, vtk

I have been looking through the Dash vtk documentation to search for a way to open STL files in the browser and be able to translate and rotate those files using python. Essentially like a mini version of CURA where you can just move the model around and rotate it on a build plate.

I was interested in Dash because it was able to draw the meshes for the models, but it only seems to plot the models/meshes. This does not give me the ability to move around the model in some fixed coordinate system and track its position. Is there a way to upload, translate, and rotate a model using Dash or any other pythonic way of achieving this? Or is javascript the only option?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.